# Unable to use jQuery script in Wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a plugin which contains a jQuery [date picker](https://codepen.io/milz/pen/xbXpWw). My PHP can see the script but is complaining about a function (possible jQuery conflicts?). Whenever the page loads, I receive the following message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function near '...jQuery(".date").datetimepicker...
```

Searching around, I thought that it might be an issue with jQuery conflicts in Wordpress, but I feel like I'm stabbing in the dark at the moment.

My directory structure is:

- plugin_directory/templates/trial_form.php
- plugin_directory/templates/calendar.js

trial_form.php:

```
<?php wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); ?>
<?php wp_register_script( 'jquery', includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ), false, NULL, true); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); ?> 

<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'script', plugins_url('calendar.js', __FILE__), array( 'jquery' )); ?>

<div id="trial-form">

<?php if ( $attributes['show_title'] ) : ?>
    <h3><?php _e( 'Trial', 'personalize-login' ); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        Choose the date for your free trial below!
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

calendar.js:

```
jQuery(function () {
var bindDatePicker = function() {
    jQuery(".date").datetimepicker({
    format:'YYYY-MM-DD',
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
        }
    }).find('input:first').on("blur",function () {
        // check if the date is correct. We can accept dd-mm-yyyy and yyyy-mm-dd.
        // update the format if it's yyyy-mm-dd
        var date = parseDate($(this).val());

        if (! isValidDate(date)) {
            //create date based on momentjs (we have that)
            date = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        }

        $(this).val(date);
    });
}

var isValidDate = function(value, format) {
    format = format || false;
    // lets parse the date to the best of our knowledge
    if (format) {
        value = parseDate(value);
    }

    var timestamp = Date.parse(value);

    return isNaN(timestamp) == false;
}

var parseDate = function(value) {
    var m = value.match(/^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{1,2})(\/|-)?(\d{4})$/);
    if (m)
        value = m[5] + '-' + ("00" + m[3]).slice(-2) + '-' + ("00" + m[1]).slice(-2);

    return value;
 }

 bindDatePicker();
});
```

Please help!

Comment: Ar you sure that jQuery.UI is loaded, because datepicker are in Jquery.UI not in basic jQuery

Comment: I'm not sure about that at all. How do you know it's in JQuery.UI and do I just specify JQuery.UI in the enqueue method?

Comment: first answer => https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
second => wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.6');

Comment: You are a gent. Thank you.